# Selecting columns to generate additional Sheet page

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, uppercase, google-query-language

I'm currently using:

```
=FILTER('Form responses 1'!B2:E&'Form responses 1'!G2:G,UPPER('Form responses 1'!G2:G="School Name"))
```

This filters responses from a Google Form into the relevant schools based on the column School Name. However, in the filter, I also want to include responses to column G whilst skipping F but can't quite figure out the formula. I've test other FILTERs, QUERYs and ARRAYs but not quite getting the solution I'm looking for.

Thank for the help!

Additional question, is there an easier way to filter into additional sheets based on the response to school name?

Comment: Please add sample data, the results you get for that input and the result you would like to get instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER({'Form responses 1'!B2:E, 'Form responses 1'!G2:G}, 
 UPPER('Form responses 1'!G2:G="School Name"))
```

Comment: Thank you - that worked! I couldn't quite figure out the order of things - this will massively help for the future!